# Not inserting one field in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysqli query that gets the name of the user and a second query that inserts this username and other fields in another table.

All the other fields are correctly inserted, but the username... My code is the following:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("**.**.com","**","**","**");
```

Getting the username:

```
 $sql_trad = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ((text_cli = '$texto' OR text_cli2 = '$texto' OR text_cli3 = '$texto' OR text_cli4 = '$texto' OR text_cli5 = '$texto' OR text_cli6 = '$texto' OR text_cli7 = '$texto' OR text_cli8 = '$texto' OR text_cli9 = '$texto' OR text_cli10 = '$texto') AND role='trad_app') LIMIT 1");
 $row_trad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_trad);
 $traductor = $row_trad['username'];
```

Inserting it:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `registro_proyectos_app` (`username`,`email`,`num_factura`,`fecha`,`hora`,`precio`,`l_origen`,
           `l_destino`,`procesado`,`facturado`,`texto_source`,`traductor`) 
           VALUES ('$user','$email','$num_factura','$date2','$hora','$precio','$l_origen','$l_destino','No','No','$texto','$traductor')");
mysqli_close($con);
```

---

Something to take into account:

- $con is correct and working for other queries.
- I tried the first query "$sql_trad" in phpmyadmin console and it showed the correct row, so the query is correct.
- The second query is inserted all correctly except the field 'traductor', which is left in blank.
- Static values correctly showing.

Comment: have you checked datatypes of field in db

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents of `$traductor` after running the first query?

Comment: what is the structure of the column 'traductor' and is it null allowed or not , also try to insert a static value in it , can you also die($traductor);  and let us know what is the actual value in it is it an array or a string or what exactly ?

Comment: And, what is the value of $user before going into the query?  You don't show the code of how that comes from $traductor.

Comment: Both are varchar but they do have different length. I imagine this is not the problem... right @RamKesavan ?

Comment: @KareemEssawy Static values are showing correctly

Comment: @alberzyzz perfect! that means the problem is in the value of the $traductor variable not in the query itself, can you show us the value of $traductor ?

Comment: is   user= $traductor or you did'nt show us where its from

Comment: @KareemEssawy i made die($traductor) and no value is shown

Comment: so that explains everything , the reason why the column is being empty because the value of $traductor is null , or maybe it contains a number as an integer value , try to check the source of the '$traductor' or try to change the structure of the db column to text instead of varchar (just for testing)

Comment: what do `var_dump($traductor);` error  reporting and error checking on the query show? we don't know what the value is for the variable, the value and schema.

Comment: @KareemEssawy I have just made var_dump($traductor) work (there is a post from an app and other get methods so it is a tricky php page...).
The info showed is: string(11) "escaMedical" which I believe is perfectly correct... But still not inserting in the other table

Comment: @alberzyzz my best guess is that its not always a string other wise you would be able to die it, try to change the structure of the db column to text instead of varchar (just for testing) , if not able to do so please try to add this line before your query '$traductor  = settype($traductor, "string");' the set type function will always change the value into a string.

Comment: @KareemEssawy apparently it worked with the following: `'$traductor = settype($traductor, "string");'`. I did many tests and all worked, thank you! If you could elaborate an answer to the question I would accept it.

Comment: @alberzyzz im glad it works now! the answer has been added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line before your query

`$traductor = settype($traductor, "string");`

the set type function will always change the value into a string.

check the [php Doc for settype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)

Comment: You can also do `$traductor = (string)$traductor;`